# Trying to understand B2C authetication with Web App and session management

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a web application (.net5, razor) that's using Azure B2C to authenticate users.

So a user opens the applications, goes through B2C to authenticate and they are now signed in. I have set the custom policies up so that for all users their session lasts 30 mins on a rolling basis:

```
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <SingleSignOn Scope="Tenant" />
      <SessionExpiryType>Rolling</SessionExpiryType>
      <SessionExpiryInSeconds>1800</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

What I'm trying to understand is what events cause the session to be increased?

Is this on any page loads (which are just within the application and don't go via B2C), or is it only when the user is passed through B2C and back to the application?

I don't want the user to be asked to re-authenticate every 30 minutes just because they've stayed on pages which are all within the application. If this is the case, do I need to pass the user through B2C on every page load?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the session is only extended when you pass the user to authenticate at Azure B2C, based on the explanation on that
[session management page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow):

> Rolling - Indicates that the session is **extended every time the user
> performs a cookie-based authentication** (default).

And it also explains how this cookie is established:

> When a user successfully authenticates with a local or social account,
> Azure AD B2C **stores a cookie-based session on the user's browser**. The
> cookie is stored under the Azure AD B2C tenant domain name, such as
> https://contoso.b2clogin.com.

So it makes sense that you have to at least hit that domain to somehow extend the session. An authentication call is a reasonable one.

You may think this does not make sense; How does this help in your case where your app does not talk to Azure anymore after user log in?

Well I believe this is because this session is just not designed for your use case. Your application can manage its own sessions and it does not need to sync up with Azure (It'd be nice if we can sync up the two, but you'd have to keep calling Azure to do that). As long as user's application session is still valid (e.g. user is actively using your app), you probably don't need to worry about whether Azure session times out. All you need to make sure is that Azure session timeout is shorter than your app's.

The `rolling` session behavior may be more useful if you use Azure B2C for SSO, so you have more than one apps that hit the same B2C tenant to login, and you would not want users to have to enter their credentials every time for every app. Having a valid session there will then help you achieve that. These authentication calls will in turn extend the session for future authentication calls.

Answer (score 0):

[Session lifetime gets increased after each successful authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/relyingparty#userjourneybehaviors). Once it has expired you won't get signed out of your application but you will need to re-authenticate to Azure B2C. You can keep the user signed in by configuring [*KeepAliveInDays*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/relyingparty#singlesignon).

**We recommend that you set the value of SessionExpiryInSeconds to be a short period (1200 seconds), while the value of KeepAliveInDays can be set to a relatively long period (30 days)**

Comment: I might not have worded my question quite right. What I meant by setting a user's session to 30 minutes and on a rolling basis, is that if a user signs in and then does nothing, if then 30+ minutes later they then click on a link to another page within the application. They should now have to reauthenticate themselves. As a organisation, we want users to have a short timescale before re-auth, rather than days. 

Also if a user to clicking links around the application but doesn't go back through B2C, how does B2C know to extent the session based on their last page load in the application?